# Using C++ class in Python 2.7 and 3.x

Tags: python, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I was trying to write a Python C++ wrapper as described in  the Tutorial: "Using a C++ class in Python".

Now to my question, is there a way to compile the Module for Python 2.7 and 3 simultaneously using catkin?
So i can import the wrapper Class in both versions?

Because currently when Importing the wrapper to python 3 this error is thrown:
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__wrapper_cpp)
Since i can only link it against the python 2 libs.

Under Python 2 it is currently working without any errors.

Thanks for your help,
Thomas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267612/using-c++-class-in-python-2.7-and-3.x/) by [Thomas_Blo](https://answers.ros.org/users/31371/thomas_blo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-07-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's doable, but pretty disgusting (macros/pragmas are very involved, due to major difference in the wrapper API). I wouldn't bother with the python 2/3 backwards compatibility, just stick with 3 if you wrote it in 3. Mixing python versions in ROS gets messy very quickly.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2017-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0